# return a List< Id:int, Name:string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I am having a function which return a list of type: List< Id:Name, Name:string >
how do you do specify in C# to return this List Type ?

Here is the code:

```
    public ?????? GetDepartements( int idRegion )
    {
        var a = (from o in _meilleurPrestaEntities.Departements
                where o.de_id_region == idRegion
                select new {Id = o.id_departement, Name = o.nom}).ToList();

        return a;
    }
```

the return is used as Json result.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You have a list of anonymous type and you can't specify anonymous type as part of a method return type (or pretty much anywhere else, unless you can use `var`).

To fix this, you have several options:

- Create normal class to represent the return type and use that in your return type.
- Use something like `List<Tuple<int, string>>`.
- Return `List<dynamic>`. This way, you will be able to treat the returned value as usual, but you will get no compile-time checking or IntelliSense.
- Return `List<object>`. This can be useful if you don't need to access the properties in the usual way, but you will only pass the result to something that uses reflection.

Comment: Hi tried out to put public Tuple<int, string> GetDepartements(int idRegion), same error, cannot convert type List<Id=int, Name=string> to Tuple :(

Comment: @dtjmsy, so make it a tuple. `new Tuple<int,string>(o.id_departement, o.nom)).ToList()`

Comment: @jb., or better: `Tuple.Create(o.id_departement, o.nom)`.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same code and just put the return value as Object (System.Object) works perfectly, thanks all, I have learnt a lot from all your comments.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using a  key value pair

```
return List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>()
```

[Edit] You'll need to modify your code slightly - it should look something like this:

```
 var a = (from o in _meilleurPrestaEntities.Departements
                where o.de_id_region == idRegion
                select new KeyValuePair<int,string>(o.id_departement,o.nom}).ToList();
```

Comment: +1, and they can also use the perhaps better-named `Tuple` if available. But it makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: @Jon, it does make a difference in that there is no key or value, so the implicit documentation in the method signature is wrong. `Tuple` would be much better here.

Comment: I tried out the List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>, no success, the return a, red curly with the error message = cannot convert expression type 'System.collection.generic.List{Id:int, Name:string}' to return type 'System.collection.generic.List<System.collection.generic.KeyValuePair<int,string>>

Comment: @svick: That's the difference I had in mind when I said "better-named". They are both immutable value types, so they will behave the same. I agree that `Tuple` is preferable, but KVP will do as well. BTW, your other three (or perhaps two) suggestions are much less desirable and IMO detract from the value of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify a type and then use that type for your return value and in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VisualStudio open to try it, but I think you can actually return `dynamic` in this case. Or you could use `ExpandoObject`.

However, as others have mentioned, the "better" way is to use something like `Tuple` or `KeyValuePair`, or don't be lazy and just make an actual model for what you will return to the view (in other words, a "View Model").